# mongodb (pymongo) update all values inside a nested array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

Im my mongoDB I have the following data :

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f3c3595271ef86d69a2909f"}
 data:{
 arr1: [ {arr2:[{a:[1 2 3],b:7},
                {a:[4 5 6],b:7},
                {a:[0 8 7],b:7},
                {a:[2 2 3],b:7}},
         {arr2:[{a:[1 2 3],b:7},
                {a:[4 5 6],b:7},
                {a:[0 8 7],b:7},
                {a:[2 2 3],b:7}},
         {arr2:[{a:[1 2 3],b:7},
                {a:[4 5 6],b:7},
                {a:[0 8 7],b:7},
                {a:[2 2 3],b:7}},
         {arr2:[{a:[1 2 3],b:7},
                {a:[4 5 6],b:7},
                {a:[0 8 7],b:7},
                {a:[2 2 3],b:7}},
         {arr2:[{a:[1 2 3],b:7},
                {a:[4 5 6],b:7},
                {a:[0 8 7],b:7},
                {a:[2 2 3],b:7}}]}}
```

I would like to delete a / empty a from everywhere in the code.
I tried something like:

```
...update({},{"$set":{"data.arr1.$[].arr2.${}.a":[]},multi=True)
```

it did not work.

how would I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it, it looks like you may have made a typo. Here:

```
update({},{"$set":{"data.arr1.$[].arr2.${}.a":[]},multi=True)
```

You have `${}` after `arr2`, this should also be `$[]`. If you change it, it will work. The update document will then look like this:

```
update({},{"$set":{"data.arr1.$[].arr2.$[].a":[]},multi=True)
```